# Docker exec Requires minimum of 2 arguments

Tags: shell, docker, docker-exec

I am using a shell script on Linux in order to execute some Docker commands :

```
docker exec -t -i test1 passwd
...
docker exec -t -i test2 passwd
```

And on the second exec command I receive the following error :

```
docker: "exec" requires a minimum of 2 arguments.
```

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have had the same mistake

```
docker exec -it gallant_bose
```

> C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: "exec" requires a minimum of 2 arguments.
> See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe exec --help'.
> Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
> Run a command in a running container

The solution, add the command **bash** in my case:

```
$ docker exec -it gallant_bose bash
```

> root@e747ffecc84d:/#

Best wishes!

## Update

Also, you can execute `docker exec -it gallant_bose /bin/bash` for some images

Comment: Thank you! After the addition of 'bash' everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `test2` exists?
I don't see any error in your command. If problem persists, can you provide the `docker ps` and `docker images` output please?

Comment: girod _s the container test2 exists, and the image that I am using (ubuntu based) is present when I run docker images.